# Is there some math problem that must use category theory to solve?

Tags: category-theory

If there is no calculus，we can't solve a problem like “surface area”.

Is there some math problem that can be solved thanks to category theory?

If there is no such math problem, it means that category theory is an “abstract theory”：it can explain things clearly, but without it, man can solve the same problems too, maybe not as gracefully.